# Calculate time difference between specific entries(containing entry date) from a ticket history for SLA

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query in place which provides me with the details about a TicketID. Every ticket has a history which records the activities in it. Like the current status, assignee, escalation level etc. Each history entry has a entry date recorded in the Ticket details.

I need to calculate SLA by considering: 
1.The time difference between entry_date when the ticket was (Escalated to Level 2) - entry date when the ticket was assigned to a (technician in Level 2) [this will be the time to accept] 2. Escalated time to Resolved time – Hold and Resolved time.(this will be the time to Resolve)

With my current query I can get the TicketId,the description, entry_date for the entries in the ticket with its description, I need two more columns that can provide me with above details for "Time to Accept" and "Time to Resolve" labels. And just FYI SLA is a service level agreement which means that every ticket should be accepted and resolved in a particular time.

[click here to see the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JreYq.png)

```
Declare @Top  int = null             --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 12
Declare @Nest varchar(25) ='|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteHB (Seq,Path,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,PARENT_ID,Lvl,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME) as (
    Select  Seq  = cast(1000+Row_Number() over (Order by PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME) as varchar(500))
           ,Path = cast(PROBLEM_TYPE_ID as varchar(500))
           ,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
           ,PARENT_ID
           ,Lvl=1
           ,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME 
     From   problem_type 
     Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(PARENT_ID,-1) else PROBLEM_TYPE_ID end
     Union  All
     Select Seq  = cast(concat(cteHB.Seq,'.',1000+Row_Number() over (Order by cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME)) as varchar(500))
           ,Path = cast(concat(cteHB.Path,'.',cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID) as varchar(500))
           ,cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
           ,cteCD.PARENT_ID,cteHB.Lvl+1
           ,cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME 
     From   problem_type cteCD 
     Join   cteHB on cteCD.PARENT_ID = cteHB.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID)
    ,cteR1 as (Select Seq,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteHB)
    ,cteR2 as (Select A.Seq,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID )
    ,cteFinalHier as (
        Select B.R1  
              ,C.R2
              ,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
              ,A.PARENT_ID
              ,A.Lvl
              ,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME
              ,A.Seq                                      -- < Included for Illustration
              ,A.Path                                     -- < Included for Illustration
         From cteHB A
         Join cteR1 B on A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID=B.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
         Join cteR2 C on A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID=C.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
    )
Select A.Job_ticket_id
      ,[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]=C.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME
      ,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] =B.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME
      ,B.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
      ,HISTORY_ENTRY.ENTRY_DATE
      ,case when HISTORY_ENTRY.ENTRY_TEXT like '%Assigned to %Level 2%%' or HISTORY_ENTRY.ENTRY_TEXT like '%Escalated to %Level 2%%' or HISTORY_ENTRY.ENTRY_TEXT like '%Status changed from % to hold%%' or HISTORY_ENTRY.ENTRY_TEXT like '%Status changed from %Hold to %%' then HISTORY_ENTRY.ENTRY_TEXT end as 'History Entry'
      ,HISTORY_ENTRY.TECH_ID
      ,A.Report_Date
      ,A.LAST_UPDATED
      ,a.STATUS_TYPE_ID AS 'Ticket_Status'
      ,A.Close_Date
      ,A.TECH_GROUP_ID
       ,A.ASSIGNED_TECH_ID
      ,TECH_GROUP_LEVEL.LEVEL_NUMBER
      ,PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME
      ,TECH_GROUP.NAME
      ,DATEDIFF(MINute, A.REPORT_DATE,A.FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE) as 'time_to_accept'                   
      , DATEDIFF(MINUTE,A.[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],A.[CLOSE_DATE]) as 'time_to_resolve'

      -----------------------only for tickets open older than 72 hours------------------------------
      ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,a.LAST_UPDATED,getdate()) as 'Time_after_Update'
      ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ,case WHEN DATEDIFF(MINute, A.REPORT_DATE,A.FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE) <= 10                        -- < for tickets accepted withiin 10 miniutes and resolved within their priority level minutes
                and DATEDIFF(MINUTE,A.[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],A.[CLOSE_DATE]) <= case PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME
                                   WHEN 'low' then 960
                                   WHEN 'medium' then 480
                                   WHEN 'high' then 120
                                   WHEN 'Urgent' then 60
                                   end
  then 1
  else 0
  end
  AS [SLA Compliant]
  ,CAST ((sum(case WHEN DATEDIFF(MINute, A.REPORT_DATE,A.FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE) <= 10                     -- < for tickets accepted withiin 10 miniutes and resolved within their priority level minutes
                and DATEDIFF(MINUTE,A.[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],A.[CLOSE_DATE]) <= case PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME
                                   WHEN 'low' then 960
                                   WHEN 'medium' then 480
                                   WHEN 'high' then 120
                                   WHEN 'Urgent' then 60
                                   end
  then 1
  else 0
  end)*100.0)/COUNT(*) as money) as Percent_Compliant
  ------------------------------JOINS--------------------------------------------------                                                                                 
 From  JOB_TICKET A
 Join  cteFinalHier B on A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID=B.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID

 INNER JOIN [SWHD01].[dbo].[PRIORITY_TYPE] ON A.[PRIORITY_TYPE_ID] = [PRIORITY_TYPE].[PRIORITY_TYPE_ID]

 INNER JOIN [SWHD01].[dbo].[STATUS_TYPE] ON A.[STATUS_TYPE_ID] = [STATUS_TYPE].[STATUS_TYPE_ID]

  inner join [SWHD01].[dbo].TECH_GROUP_LEVEL on A.TECH_GROUP_LEVEL_ID=TECH_GROUP_LEVEL.ID

 join TECH_GROUP on TECH_GROUP.ID= TECH_GROUP_LEVEL.tech_group_id


join HISTORY_ENTRY on a.JOB_TICKET_ID=HISTORY_ENTRY.JOB_TICKET_ID



 Cross Apply (Select Top 1 * from cteFinalHier Where B.R1 between R1 and R2 and Lvl=1) C

 -------------Tickets for the Last 6 months---------------------------------------------------

 where datediff(MONTH, A.REPORT_DATE, getdate()) <= 6
and TECH_GROUP.NAME like '%NOC%'
 and LEVEL_NUMBER ='2'

 Group By C.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME,a.JOB_TICKET_ID,B.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME,B.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID, a.REPORT_DATE,a.CLOSE_DATE,SWHD01.dbo.PRIORITY_TYPE.PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME,a.FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE,B.R1,a.LAST_UPDATED,a.STATUS_TYPE_ID,a.TECH_GROUP_ID,TECH_GROUP_LEVEL.LEVEL_NUMBER,TECH_GROUP.NAME,a.ASSIGNED_TECH_ID,HISTORY_ENTRY.ENTRY_DATE,HISTORY_ENTRY.ENTRY_TEXT,HISTORY_ENTRY.TECH_ID
 Order By B.R1
```

Comment: provide sample data and ouput

Comment: What have you already tried and what problem(s) did you experience?

Comment: I have provided the expectated output @Mani

Comment: Provide sample data of history table